# Minimal value of the quadratic form $\mathbf{x}^t A \mathbf x$ subject to the contraint $\mathbf{x}^t \mathbf x = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Please help me solving this question:

Let $m$ be the minimal value of the quadratic form $\mathbf{x}^t A \mathbf x$ subject to the contraint $\mathbf{x}^t \mathbf x = 1$.

Given a vector on the unit circle in which this minimal value is attained.

$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-\frac{7}{4} & \frac{3}{4}\\
\frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4}
\end{array}\right] $$

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}
\end{array}\right] \text { or } \left[\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}
\end{array}\right]$$

I calculated the eigenvectors and eigenvalues and tried to fill them in to the formula:
$$\mathbf x_k = c_1 \lambda_1^k \mathbf v_1 + c_2 \lambda_2^k \mathbf v_2$$
and this is not really solving the problem.

What do I need to do tho solve this question?

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)

Comment: The answer is eigenvectors, but your eigenvectors are not correct.

Comment: @A.Γ. Make that an answer, since it solves the problem entirely

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange function is
$$
L\left(x,\lambda\right)=x^{\top}Ax+\lambda\left(1-x^{\top}x\right)
$$
Derivative wrt $x$ yields $2Ax-2\lambda x=0\implies\left(A-\lambda I\right)x=0$
means $x$ is in the null space of $A-\lambda I$ and $\left|A-\lambda I\right|=0$.
So the rule is to find the eigenvectors of $A$. Then, normalize them to $x^{\top}x=1$.